# Flow - property missing in Event type

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have the following function:

```
createComment = (e: Event) => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    e.preventDefault()
    ...
  }
}
```

but Flow is returning this error `Property key is missing in Event`. How do I resolve this?

Comment: It should be `SyntheticKeyboardEvent`. More info here https://flow.org/en/docs/react/events/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I should use `KeyboardEvent` instead of `Event`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use SyntheticKeyboardEvent instead of Event

So change

```
    createComment = (e: Event) => {
           if (e.key === 'Enter') {
               e.preventDefault()
               ...
            }
     }
```

To

```
     createComment = (e: SyntheticKeyboardEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
          if (e.key === 'Enter') {
              e.preventDefault()
              ...
          }
     }
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: `Property key is missing in SyntheticEvent `

Comment: That's because it should be `SyntheticKeyboardEvent`